# Quickly add identical metadata when inserting thousands of records in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, performance, mongodb

I want to [insert an array](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-multiple-documents) with thousands of objects into a MongoDB collection.

```
db.col.insert(
   [
     { },
     { },
     { } // A couple of 1000s more
   ],
   {
       ordered : false,
       writeConcern : 0
   }
);
```

However, I also want to identify these groups using metadata. Every record from the array needs to have some data assigned, and this data is identical for all records in the array.

Is there a way I can insert all documents, and for all documents also set e.g.:

```
{
    dateTime : '111111111',
    groupId  : 'some hash',
    batchId  : 'other hash'
}
```

**without** manually adding this to the thousands of records in the array manually? That would be a big performance drop (and just ugly).

I used to add these records as one array with the metadata:

```
{
    dateTime : '111111111',
    groupId  : 'some hash',
    batchId  : 'other hash',
    batchArr : [ array with thousands of records]
}
```

and use `$unwind` on it. However, this is no longer possible because the the number of records are starting to exceed MongoDB's [16 MB BSON size limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents).

Answer (score 2):

This would be a pretty good candidate for the **[Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk)** operations. There are two types of bulk operations:

- **Ordered bulk operations**. These operations execute all the operation in order and error out on the first write error.
- **Unordered bulk operations**. These operations execute all the operations in parallel and aggregates up all the errors. Unordered bulk operations do not guarantee order of execution.

Consider initialising a **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk)** operations builder and add a series of insert operations to add multiple documents in batches, thereby streamlining your performance:

```
var bulk = db.col.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    objectList = [{}, {}, ..., {}], // array with thousands of records 
    counter = 0,
    metadata = {
        dateTime : '111111111',
        groupId  : 'some hash',
        batchId  : 'other hash'
    };      

objectList.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj["dateTime"] = metadata.dateTime;
    obj["groupId"] = metadata.groupId;
    obj["batchId"] = metadata.batchId;

    bulk.insert(obj);
    counter++;

    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();             
        bulk = db.col.initializeOrderedBulkOp();            
    }
});

// Catch any under or over the 500's
if (counter % 500 != 0) {
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Comment: Extra points for using `Bulk API`. Upvoted. However, this still does `forEach()` on the massive array, and this causes overhead. I'm removing as many `forEach()`es as possible to cut down execution time, and I was especially wondering if there's a way to do do this query without adding more `forEach()`.

Comment: The `forEach()` method merely represents a loop that adds objects for bulk execution and as long as you stick to adding large batches of the same class of operations, in this case batch inserts, you can be sure of matching your code with the underlying write protocol. Try setting up a synthetic micro-benchmark where you insert 1000 records without the bulk API  and one with the Bulk API, you will see a massive performance gain. So, realise that the `forEach()` acts as a loop to prepare the bulk operations batches.

Comment: I don't see it. Either my microbenchmark is wrong, or `col.insertMany(array)` is just as optimized as `bulk`. I'm not sure.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using by the way, because the Bulk API is only available for version 2.6 and up?

Comment: Using `2.6.11`  as the lowest version.

Comment: `forEach` type adding of metaData and preparing bulk takes a __lot__ of overhead compared to a single document with a huge array. How do I get around that problem? See [Stack Overflow: How can I improve MongoDB bulk performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843863/how-can-i-improve-mongodb-bulk-performance)