# How can I improve MongoDB bulk performance?

Tags: arrays, node.js, performance, mongodb, bulkinsert

I have this object with some metadata and a big array of items. I used to store this in mongo, and querying it by `$unwind`ing the array.
However, in extreme cases, the array becomes so big that I run into 16MB BSON limitations.

So I need to store each element of the array as a separate document. For that I need to add the metadata to all of them, so I can find them back.
[It is suggested that I use bulk operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544479/quickly-add-identical-metadata-when-inserting-thousands-of-records-in-mongodb) for this.

However, performance seems to be really slow. Inserting one big document was near-instant, and this takes up to **ten seconds**.

```
var bulk        = col.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var metaData    = {
    hash            : hash,
    date            : timestamp,
    name            : name
};

// measure time here

for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) { // 6000 items
    var item = array[i];

    bulk.insert({ // Apparently, this 6000 times takes 2.9 seconds
        data        : item,
        metaData    : metaData
    });

}

bulk.execute(bulkOpts, function(err, result) { // and this takes 6.5 seconds
    // measure time here
});
```

Bulk inserting 6000 documents totalling 38 MB worth of data (which translates to 49 MB as BSON in MongoDB), performance seems unacceptably bad.
The overhead of appending metadata to every document can't be that bad, right? The overhead of updating two indexes can't be that bad, right?

Am I missing something? Is there a better way of inserting groups of documents that need to be fetched as a group?

It's not just my laptop. Same on the server. Makes me think this is not a configuration error, rather a programming error.

Using MongoDB `2.6.11` with node adapter `node-mongodb-native 2.0.49`

**-update-**

Just the act of adding the metadata to every element in the bulk accounts for **2.9 seconds**. There needs to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Note than "internally" both the driver and MongoDB itself are going to break this down into 1000 operations at a time ( therefore this is actually doing 6 send/receive interactions ) and also that no single request can actually exceed 16MB, so there is some "breaking up" of this request anyway. Also consider that as `bulk.insert()` is being called then nothing is actually being sent to the server, but building up data in memory ( a second time effectively ). You would be better off approaching this directly from reading the source. Also, what is the point of adding the same data to everything?

Comment: I need to be able to find the data grouped. E.g. 60000 documents from `timestamp`, of which 10000 have the same `name` and 6000 share a `hash`. But the hash also appears in diferent `timestamp`s. I need to select a combination of those three properties. I'm just trying to imitate what I did when all the documents were in an array in a single document. This is the answer I got from Stack Overflow, but if you have a better idea, please be my guest! :)

Comment: Might be a bit broad as to your modelling goal without a specific question. But wandering a bit off topic for the immediate issue. So you have an array of 60,000 documents. Where are you getting it from? Can you include the code for the source read. Because I'm not sure that you are grasping that you are storing 60,000 documents in memory, then making another copy of 60,000 documents again in memory before anything gets done. I think this will get much better throughput if it can be processed in chunks directly from the source.

Comment: It's a bit complicated. I'm creating a cache from many combined sources and this takes a long time. This only needs to happen once. The resulting documents are formatted in a way that we can use them directly, and querying them is very fast and functional. The only problem is storing them. There was no problem when it was just an array, but since we grew out of the 16MB limit we need to store all array elements separately, and this takes a _lot_ more time. I'm looking for a solution for that. Discussing how this collection came to be in the first place is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: It's really better if your "big explanations" are not comments by yourelf but edits to your question. I am just explaining the basic principle of redundancy in building two copies in memory for update. Perhaps you should explain your desired process in a series of smaller questions. The end result might lead you to a different and possibly more effective design than you currently have.

Comment: I did. Q1: How to handle 16MB limit? A1: Use separate documents. Q2: How do I add the metadata to those documents? A2: Use bulk inserts. Q3: How do I improve that performance? (this question)

Comment: Yet your answers do not suit, which is exactly my point. You need to look at this from the source. On a basic level, it would seem to me that your basic goal here is *"accumulate data"*, where maybe it is better to accumulate in the database rather than in memory ( or at least flush periodically ), but you haven't asked "that" question yet.

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. However, assume I have a good reason, I'm not looking on advise how _not_ to do what I'm about to do. I'm looking to insert one array that is too big for a single document. I just can't believe there is _so much overhead_ for something that takes 4 queries in stead of one. Perhaps you are right and I should ask a question differently.

Answer (score 1):

Send the bulk insert operations in batches as this results in less traffic to the server and thus performs efficient wire transactions by not sending everything all in individual statements, but rather breaking up into manageable chunks for server commitment. There is also less time waiting for the response in the callback with this approach.

A much better approach with this would be using the **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst)** module so even looping the input list is a non-blocking operation. Choosing the batch size can vary, but selecting batch insert operations per 1000 entries would make it safe to stay under the 16MB BSON hard limit, as the whole "request" is equal to one BSON document.

The following demonstrates using the **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst)** module's whilst to iterate through the array and repeatedly call the iterator function, while test returns true. Calls callback when stopped, or when an error occurs.

```
var bulk = col.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0,
    len = array.length,
    buildModel = function(index){   
        return {
            "data": array[index],
            "metaData": {
                "hash": hash,
                "date": timestamp,
                "name": name
            }
        }
    };

async.whilst(
    // Iterator condition
    function() { return counter < len },

    // Do this in the iterator
    function (callback) {
        counter++;
        var model = buildModel(counter);
        bulk.insert(model);

        if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
            bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
                bulk = col.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
                callback(err);
            });
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    },

    // When all is done
    function(err) {
        if (counter % 1000 != 0) {
            bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
                console.log("More inserts.");
            }); 
        }           
        console.log("All done now!");
    }
);
```

Comment: Mongo does this automatically. The default (limit) is 1000. You should only do this for a specific reason, for example if 1000 documents would already exceed the 16MB limit, so you can manually execute. But you would need to take a number smaller than 1000 for it to make sense.